# MICRO 800 assembler?

Tags: assembly, data-general

I'm reading (well, writing...) about the [FLOW language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOW_(programming_language)) and it mentions the "MICRO 800 assembler". This was in the early 1970s, and I can't imagine what this might be. The context suggests it was on the Nova. Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Nova Assembler code was just called DG Assembler - didn't have a name like Micro800.

Comment: I am thinking this is perhaps a 3rd party assembler for the Nova. But it could be some other similar machine like a PDP-8 or maybe an HP 2100.

Comment: The other alternative is microprogramming but that was only available on the eclipse range: not the novas and the eclipses only came out in the mid 80s.

Comment: "Flow was later ported by two UCSD graduate students to Nova assembler language. Later ports included MICRO 800 assembler, BASIC and Algol." = There is nothing in there to tie Micro 800 to the Nova. It could just as well read "Later ports included ZX-80 BASIC, ...".

Comment: @paxdiablo - ahhh... and that found the MICRO 800, a not very well known mini of 1969.

Comment: Hmmm, to further confuse issues, there are TWO, one from Micro Systems and another from Microdata Corp, both in 1969. I suppose they are both the same after a name change...